# Polly downloading mp3 as int? Trying to put it up to S3 using Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-polly

I'm a beginner with Python. Trying to figure out what's wrong with Polly, since it doesn't seem to be outputting a valid mp3.

I'm following these tutorials loosely: [1](https://github.com/ranman/polly_widget/blob/master/lambda/build_polly.py) [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=evKrNTw1nr4)

but since I'm not concatenating any files due to character restriction I don't think I need to use Audiosegment or ffmpeg right?

Here's my code:

```
import hashlib
import json
import tempfile
import praw, boto3
import os
import random
import time

polly = boto3.client('polly')
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3r = boto3.resource('s3')

DEFAULT_VOICE = os.getenv("DEFAULT_VOICE", "Celine")
SAMPLE_RATE = os.getenv("SAMPLE_RATE", "8000")
BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv("BUCKET_NAME", "pollybotreddit")
FILE_FORMAT = os.getenv("FILE_FORMAT", "mp3")

def build_sound(content, voice = 'Justin', SampleRate = SAMPLE_RATE):
    for text in content:
        resp = polly.synthesize_speech(
            OutputFormat = "mp3",
            Text = text,
            TextType = "text",
            VoiceId = voice
        )
    with open('test.mp3' , 'wb') as f:
        sound = f.write(resp['AudioStream'].read())
    return sound

def lambda_handler(event, content):
    slashr = event.get('subreddit')
    voice = event.get('voice', 'Joanna')
    if not slashr:
        raise ValueError("Bad Request: Not a subreddit")

    reddit = praw.Reddit('bot1')
    sub = reddit.subreddit(slashr)
    titles = []
    for submission in sub.hot(limit=5):
        if not submission.stickied:
            titles.append(submission.title)
    article = random.choice(titles)

    sound_data = build_sound(article, voice=voice)
    final = sound_data + '.mp3'


    s3.put_object(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, ACL='public-read', Body=final, Key=article)

    item = {
        'subreddit': slashr,
        's3': "{}/{}/{}".format(s3.meta.endpoint_url, BUCKET_NAME, article)
        }
    return item

lambda_handler({'subreddit':"politics"}, None)
```

error gives me this:

```
  File "pollybot.py", line 91, in <module>
    lambda_handler({'subreddit':"politics"}, None)
  File "pollybot.py", line 79, in lambda_handler
    final = sound_data + '.mp3'
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

and if I take out

```
final = sound_data + '.mp3'
```

Polly's output is still an int, not a File object, so it gives me this

```
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter Body, value: 3493, type: <class 'int'>, valid types: <class 'bytes'>, <class 'bytearray'>, file-like object
```

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with polly. Your `build_sound` function returns the value of `file.write`, which is an int (the number of bytes written). Not sure why you are writing to a file at all in that function, though.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman Thanks for the clarification. But how exactly would I go about making the mp3 and putting it up on S3 for each lambda function then? I mainly took the `build_wave_file` from [this example](https://github.com/ranman/polly_widget/blob/master/lambda/build_polly.py) to create my `build_sound` function.

Comment: Surely you just want to return `resp['AudioStream']`, which you would then pass as the body of the `s3.put_object` call?

Comment: Alternatively, call `StartSpeechSynthesisTask ` which streams the audio directly to S3, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/asynchronous.html

Comment: with passing `resp['Audiostream']` into the body of `s3.put_object` I get `TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not StreamingBody` I'll look for fixes and also try your other option if necessary

Comment: Possibly `resp['AudioStream'].read()`, sorry.

Comment: @DanielRoseman It works! Obviously there's other things I need to fix but thanks for solving this specific issue!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Daniel Roseman, the following code block worked for me:

```
def build_sound(content, voice = 'Justin', SampleRate = SAMPLE_RATE):
    for text in content:
        resp = polly.synthesize_speech(
            OutputFormat = "mp3",
            Text = text,
            TextType = "text",
            VoiceId = voice
        )
    filetospeech = resp['AudioStream'].read()
    return filetospeech
```